# interactive unkillable shell during shutdown

Tags: linux, centos, systemd

My VBox CentOS 7 image with some custom software has a problem that it shuts down too long. I'd like to find the culprit by running shell commands from the console, but all shells are being killed.

I tried to protect the bash process with the "at"-sign (`@`) and ignore `HUP`, but it's apparently not enough.

```
# cat /tmp/dontkillme.rc
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi
trap '' HUP
#

# TERM=linux setsid bash -c 'exec -a "@dontkillme" /bin/bash --rcfile /tmp/dontkillme.rc -i <>/dev/tty8 >&0 2>&1'
# 

# poweroff
#
```

This enables bash on `tty8` for some time, but in the end it's being killed too, but the image stays powered on